# How To Chant ॐ?

Tags: mantras, om

How To Chant ॐ with respect to Time and Breath..and how long should each chant Be.

I know ॐ is devided into AUM..

While Chanting ॐ silently, within Mind

Is there Any Instruction Like

Say A for 3 second, while Inhaling

Say U for 3 second, while Holding breath

Say M for 3 second, while exhaling.. So Total 9 second for a Single ॐ Chant.

And which part of Day is Best to Chant ॐ.

Whats the difference between OM and AUM,

Is there rule like OM is used at the beginning of Mantra and AUM is used for Meditation..

Scriptural references..

Comment: AUM is expansion of Om where Br(A)ma, Vishn(U) and (M)ahesh which is beginning, middle and end of creation and its a repetitive cycle of Shabd Brahman. Aum/Om is mantra of Nirguna Brahman, where true mantra is Om Shanti(where Shanti is practical manifested peace, not verbal). Glory of Om is described in 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandukya_Upanishad . Worship of Nirguna Brahman using Om and formlessness is difficult in tamsik Kaliyuga, thats why Puranas of trinity are made mainstream.

Comment: @ManuKumar I know those info.. My main Q is about chanting, How To Chant ॐ with respect to Time and Breath.

Comment: Om is not the only way of meditation. Om should not be chanted solo without initiation into Sanyass as explained in Bhagvatam-Uddhava Geeta under rules of Sanyass, for any householder, rather with names of trinity or other deities or in Gayatri.